# Number of permutations where $621$ and $231$ are subsequences

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given $S_6$, I want to find how many elements contain $621$ or $231$ as subsequences, meaning that the numbers come one after another in the permutation. For example $632541$ is a valid permutation, but $615432$ is not.

I proved that there are 120 permutations, where one of both holds and found computationally that the number for the intersection is 30, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of permutations in $S_6$ which contain $621$  as a subsequence is $\binom{6}{3}\cdot 3!=120$. The same for $231$. In the intersection we find the permutations which contain $6231$ as a subsequence and their number is $\binom{6}{4}\cdot 2!=30$.
Therefore the answer is $120+120-30=210$.

Comment: Oh my, it was that easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: $\binom{6}{4}$ ways to choose the positions of $6$,$2$,$3$,$1$ in order multiplied by $2$, the permutations $45$ or $5$$.

Comment: Shouldn’t the $621$ be contiguous so there are only $3\cdot 3!$ of them?

Comment: Is it this simple?  Taking a piece of the problem, the permutations which include ( 6 2 1 ) should account for partitions of 6, which give us these "types" of permutations to count: ( 6 2 1 X Y Z ), ( 6 2 1 X Y ) ( Z ), ( 6 2 1 X ) ( Y Z ), ( 6 2 1 X ) ( Y ) ( Z ), ( 6 2 1 ) ( X Y Z ), ( 6 2 1 ) ( X Y ) ( Z ), ( 6 2 1 ) ( X ) ( Y ) ( Z ).

Comment: 621 as a subsequence does not mean that 6,2,1 are contiguous. The permutation 634251 contains 621 as a subsequence. See also the example given by OP.

Comment: @ThomasBitonti You are considering a different problem...

Comment: I was thinking that the numbers must be contiguous, but even allowing for discontinuous sequences, don't we still need to account for the different partitions?  Also, if we are considering the permutation group $S_6$, how do we count different representations of the same element (e.g., (6 2 1) vs (2 1 6))?

Comment: @ThomasBitonti  You are using the cycle notation, but here $634251$ means that $1\to6$, $2\to 3$, $3\to 4$, $4\to 2$, $5\to 5$, , $6\to 1$